# XCode project doesn't acknowledge changes

Tags: xcode

It got stuck on 2 syntax errors. So I fixed them (definitely) but the errors stayed. I commented out the lines - the errors stayed. I cleaned a billion times, manually deleted the build dirs - they stayed. I deleted the files and made sure they weren't in the build list...the errors stayed!

I literally don't know what to do, and it's the most impossible thing to search for because it's so vague and such a newbie-like problem that all of the answers are super basic things that I tried in the first 5 minutes. 
I'm using a hackintosh and the drive is NTFS, using paragon to make it read/write. Could it be something to do with that? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Then you're probably not editing the files you think you are editing. If you search for your files on the disk, do you find multiple files with the same name but in different locations?